# Writing a query that shows the total amount of the fines accumulated for all cars which have accumulated more than 1000 of fines

Tags: mysql

I can't figure out how to write a query in SQL.

Here are my tables,

```
CREATE TABLE offences (
oOffenceID VARCHAR (30),
oDescription VARCHAR (200),
oMaximumFine INT (10),
CONSTRAINT o_pk
PRIMARY KEY (oOffenceID)
);

CREATE TABLE drivers (
dPersonID VARCHAR (30),
dLicenseNumber INT (20),
dLicenseRemoved ENUM('yes','no'),
dExpiryDate DATE,
CONSTRAINT d_pk
PRIMARY KEY (dLicenseNumber),
CONSTRAINT d_fk
FOREIGN KEY (dPersonId)
REFERENCES People (pPersonID)
);

CREATE TABLE people (
pPersonID VARCHAR (30),
pName VARCHAR (30),
pAddress VARCHAR (50),
pNIN VARCHAR (30),
CONSTRAINT p_pk
PRIMARY KEY (pPersonID)
);

CREATE TABLE vehicle (
vOwnerID VARCHAR (30),
vColour VARCHAR (30),
vModel VARCHAR (30),
vMake VARCHAR (30),
vVehicleID VARCHAR (30),
CONSTRAINT v_pk
PRIMARY KEY (vVehicleID),
CONSTRAINT v_fk
FOREIGN KEY (vOwnerID)
REFERENCES People (pPersonID)
);

CREATE TABLE fines (
fFineID INT (30) AUTO_INCREMENT,
fVehicleID VARCHAR (30),
fPersonID VARCHAR (30),
fTime DATE,
fAmount INT (10),
fOfficerStatement VARCHAR (500),
fOffenceID VARCHAR (30),
CONSTRAINT f_pk
PRIMARY KEY (fFineID),
CONSTRAINT f_fk
FOREIGN KEY (fVehicleID)
REFERENCES vehicle (vVehicleID),
CONSTRAINT f_fk1
FOREIGN KEY (fPersonID)
REFERENCES people (pPersonID),
CONSTRAINT f_fk2
FOREIGN KEY (fOffenceID)
REFERENCES offences (oOffenceID)
);
```

I need a query that shows the car VehicleID, the name of the Owner and the total amount of the fines accumulated for all cars which have accumulated more than 1000 of fines. Can anyone see how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully this will get you going in the right direction:

```
select fVehicleId,p.pName,sum(fi.totalFines) as totalFinesOver1000ForPerson
from 
(select fVehicleId,sum(fAmount) as totalFines
from fines f
group by fVehicleId
having sum(fAmount) > 1000) fi
inner join vehicle v on v.vVehicleID = fi.fVehicleId
inner join people p on v.vOwnerId = p.pPersonId
group by fVehicleId,p.pName;
```

Comment: COuld I ask what does this mean p.pName, as in what does p. mean before the pName?

Comment: you're correct - this is called 'Aliasing' in SQL. You can read more about it here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp

Comment: On closer analysis this solution didn't work, but it did introduce me to Group by which resulted in me figuring out this solution...

Comment: `SELECT vVehicleID, pName, SUM(fAmount) 
FROM  vehicle, people, fines 
WHERE 
fAmount > 1000
AND
pPersonID=fPersonID
AND
vVehicleID=fVehicleID
GROUP BY fVehicleId`

Answer (score 0):

```
Select a.vVehicleID,
       b.pName,
       sum(d.fAmount) fine 
from vehicle a,people b,fines d,drivers e 
where a.vVehicleID=d.vVehicleID and d.fPersonID=e.dPersonID and d.fPersonID=a.vOwnerID and
      b.pPersonID = e.dPersonID 
group by a.vVehicleID,b.pNamem
having fine > 1000;
```

This should work